# Making ajax in php on on-form elements?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this kind of button

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-action="1">Delete record</button>
```

What i need when someone click on that button, to get data-action atributte and make mysql query, something like this

```
$(function() {
    $("button).click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: 
                success: function(msg){
                    $(".alert-success").toggle();
                    $("#form-content").modal("hide");    
                },
            error: function(){
                $(".alert-error").toggle();
                }
                  });
    });
});
```

The problem is here how to pass data-action attribute to process.php?
I know i data: i can pass form element, but how attribute, and later to handle in php?

Answer (score 0):

I would choose this approach:

1. Click button
2. Call a function that elaborates the attribute and generate a valid url request with all the parameters you need that will be later on processed
3. Call ajax and pass the url you have just generated. Get rid of "data" in ajax.

The ajax request will be like :

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php?"+generateRequest()
        ...
```

Where `generateRequest()` returns something like "action=1".

Your final ajax url will be like process.php?action=1

How does this sound to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `data-action` attribute can be done by using either jQuery `data("action")` function or `attr("data-action")`.

To pass the information to your server you want to create a `POST` request and send it to a URL like `process.php?action=deleterecord`. The *action*, deleting a row, is static so that part goes into the url. The information which row to delete goes into the data part of the request.

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var action = $(this).data("action");
        var recordId = /* your record id */;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php?action=" + action,
            data: { recordid: recordId },
            success: function(msg){
                $(".alert-success").toggle();
                $("#form-content").modal("hide");    
            },
            error: function(){
                $(".alert-error").toggle();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

As for the php script, you have to read the `$_GET` and `$_POST` super variables.

```
switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case 'deleterecord':
        $recordId = parseInt($_POST['recordid']);
        // don't forget to validate your input
        // and then delete the record
        break;
}
```